# comparing two dict in python to get the maximum value for similar key

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have these 2 dicts:

```
a={"test1":90,  "test2":45,  "test3":67,  "test4":74}
b={"test1":32,  "test2":45,  "test3":82,  "test4":100}
```

how to extract the maximum value for the same key to get new dict as this below:

```
c={"test1":90,  "test2":45,  "test3":82,  "test4":100}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Will you please give your code u tried to achive this result ?

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this,

```
>>> a={"test1":90, "test2":45, "test3":67, "test4":74} 
>>> b={"test1":32, "test2":45, "test3":82, "test4":100}
>>> c = { key:max(value,b[key]) for key, value in a.iteritems() }
>>> c
{'test1': 90, 'test3': 82, 'test2': 45, 'test4': 100}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> a={"test1":90, "test2":45, "test3":67, "test4":74} 
>>> b={"test1":32, "test2":45, "test3":82, "test4":100}
>>> c={ k:max(a[k],b[k]) for k in a if b.get(k,'')}
{'test1': 90, 'test3': 82, 'test2': 45, 'test4': 100}
```

Comment: I think you're missing keys that are part of `b` but not of `a`.

Comment: we need that elements are in two dicts. So if there's one in b and not in a, we can't perform max operation

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but still a variant:

```
from itertools import chain

a = {'test1':90, 'test2': 45, 'test3': 67, 'test4': 74}
b = {'test1':32, 'test2': 45, 'test3': 82, 'test4': 100, 'test5': 1}

c = dict(sorted(chain(a.items(), b.items()), key=lambda t: t[1]))
assert c == {'test1': 90, 'test2': 45, 'test3': 82, 'test4': 100, 'test5': 1}
```